# Razor to produce single line text

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to write Razor view helper to produce single line content:

```
@helper Format(obj) {
   <text>
       @obj.Title
       @obj.FormatInnerData() (obj.User != null)
       {
          @obj.User.Name
       }
   <text>
}
```

But of course I get

```
Title
Inner Data
User Name
```

Currently I have to do

```
<text>@obj.Title @obj.FormatInnerData() @(obj.User != null ? obj.User.Name : "")</text>
```

to produce text output as single line without line breaks, but this can grow quite long / unreadable for many properties.

In other words, how do I more conveniently use Razor to generate text content, not markup content?

UPD: Ideally that would be something like

```
   <content>@obj.Title</content>
   <content>@obj.Format()
 @obj.User.Name</content>
```

i.e. only parts between content tags go into output stream. Of course maybe a simpler syntax, like @: instead of <text>.

An example use case would be to generate JavaScript string content with markup inside, or, generate text files with license details in format "Key: Name (details)" on each line, padded with spaces for grouping.

Comment: In both your examples, it doesn't really matter if you use the `<text>` tag or not. That tag's purpose is primarily for transitioning from code to markup where it would otherwise be ambiguous (for the parser).

Comment: if you care this much about formatting, why not just use custom html helper instead of razor helper?

Comment: Because it gets very ugly, see "Currently I have to do" in question.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly, you would like a way to specify your views with multiple lines, while the eventual output would be everything on one line?

I don't think that's possible out of the box, but you could write your own Custom RazorViewEngine (derived from the actual RazorViewEngine), which trims out all the newlines before returning the view.

Comment: I don't want all views to be on single line. I want to control that from the view - this piece as single line, here I want newlines. I.e. as example I want to produce text files, not HTML markup. I could do @Html.MyHelper(obj).ToString().Replace("\n", "") - but this is ugly and still I don't control from within the helper where to put \n and where do not.

Comment: @queen3: you could implement your own tag e.g. `<singleline>` into your custom viewengine, just like the razorengine has the `<text>` tag. It would then only do the trimming of the newlines out of those singleline-blocks.

Comment: @queen: Note that that would go in a custom RazorEngineHost, not the RazorViewEngine.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper method like that one

```
public class MyHelper
{
    public static string JoinedString(string delimiter, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return string.Join(delimiter, parameters);
    }
}
```

And then call it in Razor view as

```
MyHelper.JoinedString("", 
         "<text>", 
         @obj.Title, 
         obj.User == null ? "" : obj.User.Name
         "</text>")
```

Note that implementation is generic, and you can use any delimiter (in this case empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
@helper Format(obj) {
   <text>
       @( obj.Title + 
          obj.FormatInnerData() + 
         obj.User != null ? obj.User.Name : ""
        )
   <text>
}
```

Comment: In real world case this is often "<div>" + obj.Title + "</div><div class='cls'>" + obj.... - too ugly and even less readable than normal but single line markup.

Comment: @queen3: apparently you're still using this to generate html? I don't understand why would you want things on one line then. That doesn't matter anyway if it gets rendered in a browser afterwards.

Comment: For example to render this to JavaScript string. Or maybe I want to generate escaped HTML markup for examples to display on the page, and it has to be formatted, because I generate PDF from that HTML later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's partially useful solution:

```
@helper Format(obj) {
   <text>@(obj.Title
     ) @(obj.FormatInnerData()
     ) @(obj.User != null ? obj.User.Name : "")<text>
}
```

I.e. we wrap **code** on next line and not content, thus newlines inside @() are not written to output.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add one line text in Razor Edit page. The solution is to use div to embrace text.

```
<div>
@{
    if (Model.Firmware.ExternalDbc != null)
    {
        <a> | </a>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Firmware.ExternalDbc.Name)
        <a> | </a>
        <a asp-page="../Dbcs/Details" asp-route-id="@Model.Firmware.ExternalDbcId">Details</a>
    }
}
</div>
```